upgrading causes rare square on icon in Dash to Panel
I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.
The extension Dash to Panel does a new thing to the running icon: it appears 'highlighted' inside a clear box. This wasn't the case before. It was neater.
Is there any way to correct it, is it a known issue?


You experience this as an issue. Others might experience this as a feature: it shows that an application is running. If, in the options of Dash to Panel, you do not see any way to change this behavior, then the best approach to handle this concern will be to file an issue to the developer of the extension.
